# User control with other controls as properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In my asp.net 4.0 application I have a standard set of tabs controls across the application that has one tab for Search, one for View and one for Reporting.  I am in the process of updating those tabs and I was hoping to be able to wrap their functionality up into a single user control since they all function in pretty much similar ways.  The issue I am having is how to create a property called SeacrhTab/ViewTab/ReportTab that allows me to assign a different user control to it depending on the area of the application (e.g. CompanySearchControl, ContactSearchControl, etc.)  Anyone ever tried to accomplish something similar?  How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to create a regular property in the partial class definition in your code behind page.  Make it public and of the type of generic class that includes all tab controls and you should be set.

I have not made other controls properties of a user control but I have certainly used all sort of other custom classes as properties of user controls, so I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Assuming `CompanySearchControl` and `ContactSearchControl` both inherit from `GenericSearchTabControlClass`, for instance:

```
public GenericSearchTabControlClass SearchTab {get;set;}
public GenericViewTabControlClass ViewTab {get;set;}
public GenericReportTabControlClass ReportTab {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum for the specific layout, view or tab definition ie: SearchTab, ViewTab etc. specify that as a Property of your UserControl, then use that propery to create, or hide and show a specific PlaceHolder or Panel depending on the required layout, or functionality.

```
public enum ControlLayoutEnum
{
    SearchTab = 0,
    ViewTab = 1,
    ReportTab = 2
}

public class TabViewControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public ControlLayoutEnum ControlLayout { get; set; }

    protected override OnInit(object sender)
    {
        // Create controls required or Hide/Show PlaceHolder or Panel etc
        switch (this.ControlLayout)
        {
            case ControlLayoutEnum.SearchTab: // Create Search Layout
                break;
    }


}
```

Comment: How would I render out the user control based on the fact that the class it needs to be is different depending on the area of the application it is in?  e.g. I have a user control for CompanySearch and a different user control for ContactSearch.  Thanks.

Comment: You could define what usercontrol Class to initialize and render based on the Enum